# Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0) in update

Tags: mysql, sql, jsp, jdbc

I have a problem for my private project, one of its function(diary modification). The problem is, java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0) in UPDATE.

I used to go to the first page of the list after I edited it, but I set it up to go directly to the view page so I could check the corrected text. I found google but there are errors about INSERT INTO, but I don't have a problem in INSERT INTO.

The only thing that changed in the code was the script tag inside the try syntax because of the variable, which caused an error before, but unlike the one that was corrected, it's not even fixed at all.

```
<%
String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/diary?serverTimezone=UTC";
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); 

try {       
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, "root","@Kanamycin1");
    int idx = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idx"));
    int pg = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pg"));
    String title = request.getParameter("title"); 
    String contents = request.getParameter("contents"); 
    contents = contents.replace("\r\n","<br>");

    String sql = "SELECT NUM FROM diary WHERE NUM=" + idx;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    sql = "UPDATE diary SET TITLE='" + title+ "' ,CONTENTS='"+ contents +"' WHERE NUM=" + idx; 
    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

    pstmt.setString(1, title);
    pstmt.setString(2, contents);

    pstmt.execute();
    pstmt.close();

    conn.close();
%>
  <script language=javascript>
   self.window.alert("Modified");
   location.href="view.jsp?idx=<%=idx%>&pg=<%=pg%>"; 
   </script>
<%  
} catch(SQLException e) {
out.println( e.toString() );
} 
%>
```

here is SQL code, for modifying writings. (using UPDATE, error occurs)

```
<%
String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/diary?serverTimezone=UTC";
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); 

try {       
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, "root","@Kanamycin1");

    String sql = "INSERT INTO diary(TIME,TITLE,CONTENTS) VALUES(?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    String time = (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")).format( new Date());
    String title = request.getParameter("title"); 
    String cont = request.getParameter("contents"); 
    cont = cont.replace("\r\n","<br>");

    pstmt.setString(1, time);
    pstmt.setString(2, title);
    pstmt.setString(3, cont);

    pstmt.execute();
    pstmt.close();

    conn.close();
} catch(SQLException e) {
out.println( e.toString() );
} 
%>
  <script language=javascript>
   self.window.alert("Saved");
   location.href="index.jsp"; 
   </script>
```

this is write code, using INSERT INTO. (there's no errors)

Because of this :

> error(java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number
>   of parameters, which is 0))

I can't use the ability to correct a sentence at all.

I want to know why this error occurs, and solve this problem in UPDATE.

Comment: Creating a physical connection with  hardcoded connection parameters in a JSP page is a **really**, really bad idea. And you shouldn't be using root to connect to the database

Comment: `sql = "UPDATE diary SET TITLE='" + title+ "' ,CONTENTS='"+ contents +"' WHERE NUM=" + idx;` should be `sql = "UPDATE diary SET TITLE=? ,CONTENTS=? WHERE NUM=?"` - anyway, as mentioned above, such code does **NOT** belong to JSP. Learn and use the [Model-View-Controller](https://www.baeldung.com/mvc-servlet-jsp) pattern.

Comment: I don't know if I'm going to do this professionally, but I'm making this out of reference to someone else's writing, so I don't know if I can connect to the root or anything. Is it possible to retrieve it from the database, add it to the database, and modify it without having to connect it as root? I don't know javascript or java. I don't even know JSP, MYSQL too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong syntax in your update clause. The code should be like this.

```
    String sql = "SELECT NUM FROM diary WHERE NUM=" + idx;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pstmt.executeQuery();

    pstmt.close();
    sql = "UPDATE diary SET TITLE=? ,CONTENTS=? WHERE NUM=?"; 
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pstmt.setString(1, title);
    pstmt.setString(2, contents);
    pstmt.setString(3, idx);
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: It would be better to also parameterize `idx` instead of concatenating it into the query string.

Comment: column of idx is NUM, and its type is INT but is it OK to String?

Comment: @Koreanraichu If idx is `int`, then use `setInt`.